# Show that for $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$, $s: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ where $s(n) = n + 1$ has infinitely many left inverses.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inverse

The exact textbook question is:

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots,\}$ of natural numbers, and let $s:N \to N$ be the shift map,
deﬁned by $s(n) = n + 1$. Prove that $s$ has no right inverse, but that it has inﬁnitely many
left inverses.

The only piece of this throwing me off is the **infinitely** many left inverses part.

The map $s$ is injective and it clearly has a valid left inverse function:

$l(n) = n - 1$.

$l \circ s = \text{id}_\mathbb{N}$

However, I don't see how $s$ has **infinitely** many left inverses. It seems to have just one left inverse.

Comment: Just checking: 0 is not a natural number in your definition?

Comment: Yes, zero is clearly excluded. This isn't _my_ definition, it's from the Artin Algebra textbook. Many different authors choose to include/exclude zero from the natural numbers set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:  Your definition of $l(n)$ (which is otherwise correct) fails for $n=1$, so you need to define that case separately.

Comment: My definition of $l(n)$ is correct for a left inverse, hence the $l$ naming convention. In $l \circ s$, $s$ is applied first, then $l$ is applied to the output of $s$. This will work on $1$. $s(1)=2, l(2)=1, l(s(1))=1$. $s$ does not have a right inverse where $s \circ r = \text{id}_\mathbb{N}$ due to the $n=1$ case.

Comment: @clay You're correct about $l(s(1))$ - but that's not Ross's point.  The point is that your $l()$ itself _isn't_ defined as a map from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$, because you haven't specified $l(1)$.

Comment: aaah.... got it... makes sense. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

What Ross Millikan is saying is that you can put an arbitrary value for $l(1)$, e.g. if you set $l(1) = 42$ it is still a left inverse. That's why there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: Although the question doesn't ask this, it is perhaps interesting to add here is that you can have a notion of unique inverse in $\mathbb{N}$, seen as an [inverse semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup), which requires that $sls = s$ and $lsl = l$ (notation: $sl = l \circ s$). In this sense, you only get a unique inverse for $s$ because the 2nd constraint limits what you can put for $l(1)$, i.e. you must set $l(1)=1$ now.

Comment: My formulation in the comment above was a bit sloppy; what I should have said was that there exists a *free inverse* semigroup of transformations on $\mathbb{N}$ with the generator $s$ and its inverse $l$ as given in the comment above, i.e. with $l(1)=1$. This semigroup is (obviously) not isomorphic with $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,...\}$ though, which is not an inverse semigroup with addition, but only a free semigroup. The ($s$,$l$)-generated free inverse semigroup of transformations is isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ with addition as the semigroup operation.